# Mercurial HGRC Force Ignore Default

Tags: mercurial

I and many of the developers on my team are constantly getting into trouble with the behavior of the default push/pull location in mercurial clones. Is there a way to turn this off system wide? I.E., I clone from ~/abc/123, and I type "hg push", and instead of pushing to that directory I get some kind of error message, like, "Sorry Dave, I can't do that."

I still want named locations that I add to the hgrc of a particular repo, I just want the default turned off.

Comment: What kind of trouble are you getting into?

Comment: People accidentally pushing to the wrong repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have people clone from a repository to which they cannot push.  You can use the `allow_push` directive in the repository's `.hg/hgrc` file to limit pushes to your team lead, release manager, etc.  That's a very common workflow, where changes flow like:

- developer: clone from SHARED
- developer: work locally
- developer: push to READY_FOR_REVIEW
- lead: push from READY_FOR_REVIEW to SHARED

Developers can still push/pull from one another, but 'SHARED' gets  a little more oversight.

Alternately, you could mandate that people use a post-clone hook that does something like:

```
[hooks]
post-clone.stopit = perl -ine 'print unless /default = /'
```

which, if you have control of the systems on which they work, you could put in `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`, but access controls on the shared repo are much easier than setting up something on everyone's system.

Comment: We already block some people from pushing, the problem is it happens very frequently, sometimes when they clone their own local. Default just isn't worth the hassle. The second part, the post-clone.stopit, sounds promising. I'll give it a try later on and if it works mark this the answer.